# Synchronously read from the store?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

So I'm using Apollo for my app's state, and am so far a little taken aback there's no equivalent to `mapStateToProps` or something.

As far as I understand, to have any data globally accessible in my store, once I get the data, I need a query to write the data to the store, then another query in my other component to go and get it.

By this point, the other component has very much mounted and rendered, so content just sort of flickers in and out.

In Redux, I can just add new data to the store in my reducers, then anything that's connected with mapStateToProps has access to it.

Is there an equivalent? Or does everything need to go through asynchronous queries? Does anyone else kind of find this an enormous pain?

For example, in one component I'm getting some invitation data:

```
   this.props.client.query({
        query: REQUEST_ACTION_DATA,
        variables: {
            id: actionData.id,
            type: actionData.type
        }
    }).then(data => {
        this.props.client.writeQuery({query: GET_ACTION_DATA, data: {
            action: {
                type: data.data.actionData.type,
                object: data.data.actionData.invitation,
                __typename: 'ActionDataPayload'
            }
        }})

        this.props.history.push('/auth/register')
    })
```

... then in my other component I have this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN);

    if (authToken) {
        this.props.history.push('/')
    }else{
        this.props.client.query({
            query: GET_ACTION_DATA
        }).then(data => {
            if(data.data && data.data.action && data.data.action.type == 'invite'){
                this.setState({
                    invitation: data.data.action.object
                })
            }
            console.log(data)
        })
    }
}
```

ignoring the fact that it's hugely unwieldy to write all this for something so simple, is there just a way to access store data without having to wait around?

Comment: Well using the `withApollo` higher order component is not the way how you would use Apollo. You want to use the `graphql` HOC (a supercharged redux `connect`) or `Query` component unless you are doing something really really special (we have a big production app and never use `withApollo`, it's an antipattern). Is this a question on how to do something _really really special_ or should I try and explain how the Apollo cache works (and how to select data from it)?

Comment: Hey @Herku, thanks so much for your response. I'm not doing anything special, really. Just passing client state around. I'm using `compose` with the graphql HOC in a couple of components, but it only appears to be a more verbose usage of withApollo. If you've got a sec, a bit of a run-down of what the difference is would be really useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `graphql` higher order component from *react-apollo* is a supercharged `connect` from redux. It will do the following:

When the component mounts it will try and execute the query on the Apollo cache. You can think of the query as a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) for selecting data not only from the server but also from the store! If this works the component is pretty much instantly filled with the `data` from the store and no remote requests are executed. If the data is not available in the store it triggers a remote request to receive the data. This will then set the `loading` property to `true`.

The Apollo cache is a normalised store very similar to your redux store. But thanks to the well thought through limitations of GraphQL the normalisation can happen automatically and you don't have to bother with the structure of the store. This allows the programmer to forget about stores, selectors and requests altogether (unless you are heavily performance optimising your code). Welcome to the declarative beauty of GraphQL frontend frameworks! You **declare** the data you want and how it gets there is fully transparent.

```
export default graphql(gql`{ helloWorld }`)(function HelloWorld({ data }) {
  if (data.loading) {
    return <div>Loading the simple query, please stand by</div>;
  }
  return <div>Result is: {data.helloWorld}</div>;
});
```

- No selector, no denormalisation happening. This is done by Apollo Client! You will get updated data when the cache updates automatically similar to Redux.
- No `componentWillMount` checks for data is in store already and triggering request actions. Apollo will make the checks and trigger queries.
- No normalisation of response data (also done by Apollo Client for you)

If you do any of the above you are probably using Apollo Client wrongly. When you want to optimise your queries [start here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/performance.html).

Comment: That was a fantastic answer, Herku. I reckon a lot of people will benefit from that. Thanks so much!